# No margin on elements next to each other on multiple lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, margin

I have a colorpicker with a right margin of 6px.
[image: Colorpicker]
I want the white square (with the black check marker) to have no right margin so that it won't wrap to the next line. Because I want to use the complete width .
I don't want to use a class with margin on 0 because when I choose one of the colors the 8th element could be the black square.
And also on smaller devices the wrap can be at the 3th element instead of the 8th element.
So I'm looking for an automatic detection method.
I would prefer a CSS solution but Javascript/jQuery is also good.
The elements are list-items with a float left

```css
ul.colors li, ul.colors li.chosen {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 3px 6px 3px 0 !important;
}
ul.colors li .colorbox {
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #dbdbd1;
}

ul.colors, ul.colors li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none
}

ul.colors { width: 180px; background: #ccc; padding: 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ajax-layered"><ul class="colors show-count"><li class="chosen filter-selected"><a href="#" data-filter="/?filter_kleur-filter=736" data-count="34" data-link="/?filter_kleur-filter=736"><div class="colorbox f_blauw" style="background:#0000ff;" alt="Blauw" title="Blauw"></div></a></li><li class=""><a href="#" data-filter="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,729" data-count="12" data-link="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,729"><div class="colorbox f_geel" style="background:#ffff00;" alt="Geel" title="Geel"></div></a></li><li class=""><a href="#" data-filter="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,752" data-count="6" data-link="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,752"><div class="colorbox f_grijs" style="background:#808080;" alt="Grijs" title="Grijs"></div></a></li><li class=""><a href="#" data-filter="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,730" data-count="19" data-link="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,730"><div class="colorbox f_groen" style="background:#008000;" alt="Groen" title="Groen"></div></a></li><li class=""><a href="#" data-filter="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,734" data-count="6" data-link="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,734"><div class="colorbox f_oranje" style="background:#ffa600;" alt="Oranje" title="Oranje"></div></a></li><li class=""><a href="#" data-filter="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,735" data-count="24" data-link="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,735"><div class="colorbox f_rood" style="background:#ff0000;" alt="Rood" title="Rood"></div></a></li><li class=""><a href="#" data-filter="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,823" data-count="2" data-link="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,823"><div class="colorbox f_roze" style="background:#ff69b4;" alt="Roze" title="Roze"></div></a></li><li class="chosen filter-selected"><a href="#" data-filter="/?filter_kleur-filter=726" data-count="34" data-link="/?filter_kleur-filter=726"><div class="colorbox f_wit" style="background:#ffffff;" alt="Wit" title="Wit"></div></a></li><li class=""><a href="#" data-filter="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,738" data-count="21" data-link="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,738"><div class="colorbox f_zwart" style="background:#000000;" alt="Zwart" title="Zwart"></div></a></li><li class=""><a href="#" data-filter="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,831" data-count="3" data-link="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,831"><div class="colorbox f_transparant" style="background:#efefff;" alt="Transparant" title="Transparant"></div></a></li></ul></div>
```

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You can use width:auto

Comment: Use `margin-left` and avoid if for first element..

Comment: @SunilPachlangia It is an empty element with a background color. So putting width to auto the boxes will be 1px.

Comment: @Rayon I had already tried that one but than I also get a left margin on the 8th/9th element witch makes a gap on the new line on the left

Comment: @RuudvanDijk Can you show us your HTML please?

Comment: I've edited my answer using the code you supplied. Could you see if this solves your issue? In my opinion it's the cleanest solution, as it works in all browsers without using extra javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a great solution for things like this. No need for javascript and it works no matter how many rows of icons you get.

```css
ul.colors li, ul.colors li.chosen {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 3px 6px 3px 0 !important;
}
ul.colors li .colorbox {
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #dbdbd1;
}

ul.colors, ul.colors li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none
}

ul.colors { width: 182px; background: #ccc; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
div.ajax-layered { width: 176px; overflow: hidden; background: #ccc; padding: 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ajax-layered"><ul class="colors show-count"><li class="chosen filter-selected"><a href="#" data-filter="/?filter_kleur-filter=736" data-count="34" data-link="/?filter_kleur-filter=736"><div class="colorbox f_blauw" style="background:#0000ff;" alt="Blauw" title="Blauw"></div></a></li><li class=""><a href="#" data-filter="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,729" data-count="12" data-link="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,729"><div class="colorbox f_geel" style="background:#ffff00;" alt="Geel" title="Geel"></div></a></li><li class=""><a href="#" data-filter="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,752" data-count="6" data-link="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,752"><div class="colorbox f_grijs" style="background:#808080;" alt="Grijs" title="Grijs"></div></a></li><li class=""><a href="#" data-filter="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,730" data-count="19" data-link="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,730"><div class="colorbox f_groen" style="background:#008000;" alt="Groen" title="Groen"></div></a></li><li class=""><a href="#" data-filter="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,734" data-count="6" data-link="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,734"><div class="colorbox f_oranje" style="background:#ffa600;" alt="Oranje" title="Oranje"></div></a></li><li class=""><a href="#" data-filter="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,735" data-count="24" data-link="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,735"><div class="colorbox f_rood" style="background:#ff0000;" alt="Rood" title="Rood"></div></a></li><li class=""><a href="#" data-filter="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,823" data-count="2" data-link="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,823"><div class="colorbox f_roze" style="background:#ff69b4;" alt="Roze" title="Roze"></div></a></li><li class="chosen filter-selected"><a href="#" data-filter="/?filter_kleur-filter=726" data-count="34" data-link="/?filter_kleur-filter=726"><div class="colorbox f_wit" style="background:#ffffff;" alt="Wit" title="Wit"></div></a></li><li class=""><a href="#" data-filter="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,738" data-count="21" data-link="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,738"><div class="colorbox f_zwart" style="background:#000000;" alt="Zwart" title="Zwart"></div></a></li><li class=""><a href="#" data-filter="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,831" data-count="3" data-link="/?filter_kleur-filter=726,736,831"><div class="colorbox f_transparant" style="background:#efefff;" alt="Transparant" title="Transparant"></div></a></li></ul></div>
```

What you do is that you make room for the margin on the right by making the inner container (in this case the `ul`) 6px larger than the outer container. If required, this could also make use of percentages. In that case you can either set everything in percentages, or use `calc()` to calculate the required width. ( `calc(100%+6px)` )

EDIT: Used your provided script and edited it accordingly. If you downvote, could you provide a comment as to why, and how the answer can be made better? Thank you.

Comment: I haven't downvoted you're answer. It's working great thanx :)

Comment: Good to hear. Wasn't directed at you if you didn't downvote. I was just wondering why someone downvoted it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can select a an nth child using the `nth-of-type` selector.

```
child:nth-of-type(8n) { 
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

This will select every 8th child and remove the right margin. So this will continue to work for next lines, as it also grabs the 16th, 24th, and so on.

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: Looks good, but on other screen widths it could be the 4th element or 5th. The website is responsive.

Comment: You could use media queries to change it for smaller screens: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score -1):

Calculating `left` position of each div element could be a solution

```js
var num = +prompt('Give me length!');
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  html += '<div class="loop"></div>';
}
document.body.innerHTML = html;
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.loop');
var MARGIN = 10;
[].forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
  if (el.getBoundingClientRect().left == MARGIN) {
    el.style.marginLeft = 0;
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
  float: left;
}
```